# GPU Memory Buffer support error on cypress open

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I've just started using cypress with React on WSL2, and whenever I run `cypress open` I get this error:
`[9462:1112/004039.496163:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported`, the GUI doesn't show up and run

I've followed [this link to use Cypress on WSL2](https://shouv.medium.com/how-to-run-cypress-on-wsl2-989b83795fb6), and I've also tried to use Cypress version 10.8 and 10.6 just to be sure (first try was the latest one at v11)

Cypress is installed under `devDependencies` in `package.json`